# How to display two text boxes as pop up using DisplayPromptAsync method in xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

When I use -

```
string result = await DisplayPromptAsync("Question 1", "What's your name?");
```

It shows only one textbox in the pop-up. But how to display two or more textboxes in the pop-up?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any example or images for what you expected? Maybe just fake one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As IvanIčin said that you can use `Rg.Plugins.Popup` to create custom popup.

Firstly, install `Rg.Plugins.Popup` bu nuget package..., then creating popup page

```
<pages:PopupPage
x:Class="FormsSample.popup.popup2"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup">
<pages:PopupPage.Content>
    <StackLayout
        Padding="20,0"
        BackgroundColor="CadetBlue"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Label Text="Question 1" />
        <Label Text="this is one question!" />
        <Entry />
        <Entry />
        <Button
            x:Name="btnsub"
            Clicked="btnsub_Clicked"
            Text="subit" />
    </StackLayout>
</pages:PopupPage.Content>

</pages:PopupPage>

 public partial class popup2 : PopupPage
{
    public popup2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnsub_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

To call this Popup Page from contentpage button.click event.

```
 private async void btnPopupButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
        await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new popup2());
    }
```

You can see the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't as it is not intended to. You can create a custom pop-up either by using some pop-up plug-in or by creating your custom code based on the native prompts (similar to what Xamarin.Forms do).

Just for the record having one input field is very generous from Xamarin as the native Android or iOS developers don't have such a prompt with the input field out of the box (though it isn't too hard to create it but still it goes much beyond one line of code).

Comment: Thank you Ivan Icin. Please tell me how to add a custom content page as a pop up. I didn't get any fine results on Google.

Comment: @NinadKulkarni in general it is not in line with site policy to recommend particular plug-ins. This one is the most popular: https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup . And it should have been quite easy to find it by the search.

Comment: Thank you Ivan Icin. I have tried this plugin. But I didn't found any tutorials on it, so I uninstalled that plugin. Please tell me how to use this plugin. I read the Getting Started page, but there is no information about how to display content pages as pop up.

Comment: Got this - https://youtu.be/0kNI3Be-uM4